# Page Table Walk in Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, operating-system, kernel

Consider the following piece of code:

```
pgd_t *pgd;
pte_t *ptep;
pud_t *pud;
pmd_t *pmd;
char *addr;

struct page *page = NULL;
struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;

pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
if (pgd_none(*pgd) || pgd_bad(*pgd))
    goto out;
printk(KERN_NOTICE "Valid pgd");

pud = pud_offset(pgd, addr);
if (pud_none(*pud) || pud_bad(*pud))
    goto out;
printk(KERN_NOTICE "Valid pud");

pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
if (pmd_none(*pmd) || pmd_bad(*pmd))
    goto out;
printk(KERN_NOTICE "Valid pmd");

ptep = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);
if (!ptep)
    goto out;

addr = ptep->pte;
printk(KERN_INFO "byte = %d\n", *(char *)__va(addr));
pte_unmap(ptep);
```

If I understand correctly, `addr` should be the physical address corresponding to the user-space virtual address. Then I should be able to dereference that using `__va`. However, it doesn't work. If I use `pte_page` and `kmap`, though, it works exactly how it is supposed to. Why does this happen? I'm on x86-64, so high memory shouldn't be a problem? Is there something else `kmap` does?

Comment: `Walk page directory` function returns the address of the page table entry in the page table directory that corresponds to virtual address parameter sent to the function. It is supposed to return a virtual address then and not a physical address. That was the case in the [tag:xv6] operating system if I am not mistaken, and it is supposed also to be your case. `__va(addr)` is basically translating a virtual address, you might then try access a portion of memory which you don't have access to and will cause your program to crash.

Comment: @TonyTannous Isn't the address in the page table a physical address? I'm directly dereferencing the page table: `addr = ptep->pte`, and then using that for `__va`.

Comment: No, the address in the page table entry isn't the physical address. You also have flag bits in that entry. And what is actually being returned is the virtual address of that page entry and not its content. I am not an expert and perhaps also mistaken so it is better to wait for more answers\opinions.

Comment: @TonyTannous Ah, I think you're right. I forgot about the bits used for access rights and other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem thanks to TonyTannous. The page table entry doesn't contain just the physical address, but also some other bits used for access rights and the like. The physical address can be obtained by masking it with `PTE_PFN_MASK`:

```
    addr = ptep->pte & PTE_PFN_MASK
```

I can then dereference it with `__va`.

Comment: I'd still be cautious as `addr` might be the virtual address of the page table entry and not its content. You might have access to  `__va(addr)` memory location but it might not be what you intended. The only way to know is to check in the Linux source code it self.